# How to bind List<string> to RadGridView DataColumn

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding, gridview, telerik

I'm using Telerik RadControls for Silverlight and I need to draw list of strings in a column. I have bound column's cellStyle to a style and added an instance of my ListCellPresenter control within that style. My control receives its internal data with the dependency property DataList. How can I bind the actual data that needs to be drawn to GridView, so that it will be accessible in ListCellPresenter?

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="gvMain" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="200" CellStyle="{StaticResource listStyle}" Header="New Column">
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
</Grid>
```

Here's the style:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="grid:GridViewCell" x:Key="listStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="grid:GridViewCell">
                    <local:ListCellPresenter DataList="{Binding DataList}"></local:ListCellPresenter>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be straightforward -- just use `DataMemberBinding` to point to the property of your row object that contains the list you want to bind to.  Ie:

```
<gridView:GridViewDataColumn 
    CellStyle="{StaticResource listStyle}" Header="New Column"  
    DataMemberBinding="{Binding TheListProperty}" />
```

(Assuming here that the `ItemsSource` of the `RadGridView` is something like `IEnumerable<MyModel>` where `MyModel` contains your objective `List<string> TheListProperty`.)

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem and saved me a lot of time.